# VS Code: How can I move the cursor by display line when wrapping in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Running VS Code with the `VSCodeVim` emulation. Line wrapping and relative numbering is enabled in the configuration:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.lineNumbers":"relative"
```

Display lines aren't numbered in the editor when a line is wrapped. Is it possible to configure VS Code to allow direct navigation to a display line?

Answer (score 16):

VSCodeVim can navigate by display lines just like Vim, with `gk` and `gj`. You can remap `j` and `k` like this:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["j"],
        "after": ["g", "j"]
    },
    {
        "before": ["k"],
        "after": ["g", "k"]
    }
]
```

Comment: I have this setting in my config and it doesn't solve my (perceived) issue I'm afraid, whereas the same keybindings in my .vimrc do

Comment: Ah, interesting. I may not understand the perceived issue, then. Can you tell me more? Fair warning: I know more about Vim than VS Code.

Comment: It looks like the vim difference is coming straight from this https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping. Regular vim has the same issue, it's just vscode's way of saying "map `j` to `gj`).

Answer (score 9):

If you have word wrap on and would like the cursor to enter each wrapped line when using <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd>, set the following in VS Code's keybindings.json settings file (as in [Andrew's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1307626/157255), [other options exist](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2924#issuecomment-476121848) but they are slow):

```
{
  "key": "up",
  "command": "cursorUp",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible"
},
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "cursorDown",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible"
},
{
  "key": "k",
  "command": "cursorUp",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && vim.mode == 'Normal' && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible"
},
{
  "key": "j",
  "command": "cursorDown",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && vim.mode == 'Normal' && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible"
}
```

Ref: [The VSCodeVim Readme](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/README.md) (after [my documentation PR](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/3623))

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to make this also work with other modes that Normal? When I removed `vim.mode == 'Normal'` check and tried to visually select a block the vim cursor wont follow anymore. Also this seems to break commands like "10j" or "2k" etc.

Comment: Yeah, this breaks chords :( I don't know any more about using it in different modes...

Comment: More important than chords, this breaks moving after having enabled selection move (capital V), and have this moving around expand the selection. It's a pity because otherwise it works fantastically (and I do not use those kinds of chords anyway).